# How to get file folder names in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have some folders and inside folders there are some files.i want to get the names of the folder(by iterating) and want to iterate through them to read the files.How can i achieve this in windows phone?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the installed folder on wp8,

```
StorageFolder InstallationFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
```

To access the files you can read more here [Accessing files in wp8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/metroapps/archive/2012/07/15/access-your-application-assets-folder.aspx)

Comment: I want to get the folders inside my App(eg : Assets)

Comment: yes get the current folder and access the folders inside

Comment: OK.How to get the folder names?

Comment: See i want to get the folder names...i have added some folders inside my project.

Comment: @JIKKU Did you find the answers!